# Notify Requestor when Case Status Changes

Tags: trigger, workflow, email-alert

I'm trying to figure out how to notify the requestor when the Case status changes. For e.g. New to Inprogress with comments.

Comment: A workflow email alert maybe?

Comment: Workflow Is used but unfortunately, it's not firing if I use evaluate the rule created, and every time it’s edited but if I use created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria. It constantly trigger every changes made. Can something be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like below :

1. Create a Workflow Rule.
2. Evaluation Criteria : Everytime the record is created or editted
3. Workflow Criteria : PRIORVALUE(Status) != Status

Add your email alert in action. This should work.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this

1. You can write a workflow on case object. I am not sure about the workflow but the trigger always work.
2. You can write a trigger on that object. The trigger should be on update. When the status is changed you can send an email to requester.